# Java map values of List into a Hashmap

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a HashMap:

```
K1, false
K2, false
K3, false
...
K1000, false
```

Initially all the values of keys are false.

I have an ArrayList:

```
K3, K10, K33,..., K417, K834, K998
```

I need to get the values of the list and mark just those values as "true" in the Hashmap for the corresponding keys. Now I know we can do this:

```
Iterate HashMap:
    Iterate List:
        if HashMap.contains(List[i])
            HashMap.put(List[i], true)
```

But we are using 2 iterations in this logic and maybe for 1000 keys it is not much of a problem, but if I want to scale it to a million keys, is there any efficient algorithm I can use to achieve above?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to `Iterate HashMap:`.

Comment: Why iterate the map? Just iterate the list and use it's value as key to set the value to `true`. 
`for (Object k : list) map.put(k, true)`

Comment: This sounds more like a set than a map.  You could just build a `Set` from the `ArrayList`'s contents; then anything that's not in the set is `false`.  Two reasons to keep the `Map` instead:  1.  Some other interface requires a `Map`;  2.  You need to throw an exception for unexpected keys like `"KMFDM"` instead of just returning `false`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to iterate `HashMap` explicitly. `hashMap.containsKey(key)` checks if a key present in the map or not in an optimized way. You need to study a bit on how HashMap works.

```
Iterate List:
    if HashMap.containsKey(List[i])
        HashMap.put(List[i], true)
```

This will work.

Comment: No, there are no stupid questions :) just a matter of time to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Map.replace()`:

```
for (E element : list) {
    map.replace(element, true);
}
```

This will only update existing keys with matching elements in `list`.

As a side note, a `Map<K, Boolean>` can often be replaced by a lighter `Set<K>`.